# Plotly R: can't make custom xaxis date ranges to work

Tags: r, plotly

This should be very simple (I think) and yet I can't get this to work for some reason. I have data like this:

```
df
           x y
1 2016-08-12 1
2 2016-08-13 2
3 2016-08-14 3
4 2016-08-15 4
5 2016-08-16 5

str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Date, format: "2016-08-12" "2016-08-13" ...
 $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

I am using plotly as follows, but it does not adjust the xaxis range to my specified custom values. Instead, uses the range of the data:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y) %>% layout(xaxis = list(range = c(as.Date('2016-08-01'), as.Date('2016-08-31'))))
```

On the other hand, if I have numeric data like this:

```
df
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

And specify a custom range like this, it works fine:

```
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y) %>% layout(xaxis = list(range = c(-5, 10)))
```

What am I missing in making data ranges work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-range (bold added by me):

> range (list)  Sets the range of this axis. If the axis `type` is
>   "log", then you must take the log of your desired range (e.g. to set
>   the range from 1 to 100, set the range from 0 to 2). **If the axis
>   `type` is "date", then you must convert the date to unix time in
>   milliseconds (the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970). For
>   example, to set the date range from January 1st 1970 to November 4th,
>   2013, set the range from 0 to 1380844800000.0**  Each named list has one
>   or more of the keys listed below.

So, you can convert your dates to the unix time in milliseconds:

```
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(
        range = 
            c(as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-08-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"))*1000,
              as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-08-31", format="%Y-%m-%d"))*1000),
        type = "date"))
```